# Spring call method in different thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have http controller, service A, service B.
There is a http request. Controller method call method from A, A method call method from B.
Controller -> A -> B

Threads and loaders:

```
Controller - [http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main], TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
A - [http-nio-8080-exec-7,5,main], TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
B - [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main], jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6ed3ef1
```

Why call to B is in different thread and class loader?
There is no async calls.

Comment: *There is no async calls*... Well apparently there are. Add code for your controller and service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForkJoinPool is implementation of ExecutorService. It parses a task to multiple smaller ones, runs in parallel threads & joins them once completed. So end result would seem synchronous. If there is no explicit call, then some internal library is using fork/join somewhere in the flow.